# rails4/redis, improve performance of items_helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am using redis for model caching - presently I have only applied it to items#index.

If $redis.get("items") returns nil, a get request to items#index takes about 435ms to load the response - which seems long to me, there is only 20-30 items in the postgresql db. Each get request thereafter only takes 7ms, which is great.

Can you see an optimizations that can be made to the code below?

```
module ItemsHelper
# Refactor
def fetch_items
    items = $redis.get("items")

    if items.nil?
        items = []

        Item.all.each do |item|
            json = {}
            json["id"] = item.id
            json["title"] = item.title
            json["description"] = item.description
            json["category"] = item.categories.length > 0 ? item.categories.first.title : 'none'
            json["price"] = item.price
            json["status"] = item.status
            json["published_date"] = item.published_date.utc.to_s
            json["seller_name"] = item.seller.name
            json["seller_latitude"] = item.seller.latitude.to_f
            json["seller_longitude"] = item.seller.longtitude.to_f
            items << json
        end
        json_items = items.to_json
        $redis.set("items", json_items)
        @items = JSON.load json_items
        return
    end

    @items = JSON.load items
end
```

end

Comment: Try to include seller and categories.  `Item.includes(:seller, :categories).each`

Comment: how will this improve performance exactly?

Comment: made no difference..

Comment: This is something you'd want to do regularly - it will avoid all the `.seller` and `.categories` queries (the n+1 queries that run on each record).  With so few records, the performance is not likely a db issue.

Comment: Add time output after each step in the action.  `puts Time.now.to_i`.  You'll find the slowest line.

Comment: actually - after playing with your suggestion some more, it really does make a big difference! Thanks